# Use GraphQL to show statistics

Tags: python-3.x, graphql, graphene-python

I'm fairly new to GraphQL and Graphene and I can't find anything that can help me with my issue so asking here now.

Basically, what I want to display is the number of active, inactive, and suspended users only for a given list. What I have in mind when doing a query is like this:

```
query{
  viewer{
    statistics(listId:5) {
      active
      inactive
      suspended
    }
  }
}
```

and receive an output like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "statistics": {
        "active": 11,
        "inactive": 12,
        "suspended": 13
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I currently have (I'm using Python):

```
class Statistic(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

    active= graphene.Int()
    inactive= graphene.Int()
    suspended= graphene.Int()

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_active(self, args, context, info):
        return 11

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_inactive(self, args, context, info):
        return 12

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_suspended(self, args, context, info):
        return 13

class Viewer(graphene.ObjectType):
    node = relay.Node.Field()
    statistics = graphene.List(Statistic, list_id=graphene.Int())

    def resolve_active_employees(self, args, context, info):
        list_id = args.get('list_id')
        if (employeelist is None):
            raise GraphQLError("Missing argument: list_id (Employee List ID)")
        return db_session.query(EmployeeModel) \
            .join(EmployeeListModel,
                  EmployeeModel.employeelist_id == EmployeeListModel.id ) \
            .filter(EmployeeModel.terminated == 0) \
            .filter(EmployeeListModel.id == employeelist)
```

So definitely I'm not getting what I wanted, instead I am receiving all the records of active (or non-terminated) users. I don't know what to use so this is all I got and stuck now.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to achieve my target output (**not really hoping for a hardcoded answer, preferably the result should come from a database query if possible**)?

I'm using:

```
graphene==1.4.1
graphene-sqlalchemy==1.1.1
graphql-core==1.1
graphql-relay==0.4.5
```

Answer (score 1):

at work we also started using graphene for the analytics part.
Although we use `graphene_django` and I did not use SQLAlchemy yet, I hope I can provide you with some ideas how you could solve your problem:

I am not sure if I understood your code correctly but you might want to have something like

```py
class Viewer(graphene.ObjectType):
    node = relay.Node.Field()
    statistics = graphene.List(Statistic, list_id=graphene.Int())

    # Use `resolve_statistics'  to define how you get the data for the 
    # statistics list
    def resolve_statistics(self, args, context, info):
        list_id = args.get('list_id')

        # Some query which filters your model for the given ID and annotates or
        # aggregates the stats
        return <you query which filters for list id and annotates stats>
```

Your query then could for example return a dictionary like 
`{'active': 11, 'inactive': 12, 'suspended':13}`.

If you choose this way, you then would need to adjust your `Statistics` object type to extract the fields value out of the dictionary:

```py
class Statistic(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

    active= graphene.Int()
    inactive= graphene.Int()
    suspended= graphene.Int()

    def resolve_active(self, args, context, info):
        return self.get('active')

    def resolve_inactive(self, args, context, info):
        return self.get('inactive')

    def resolve_suspended(self, args, context, info):
        return self.get('suspended')
```

I am not really sure if this is what you want, but maybe it gives you some idea.
What we do is for example using the `django_filter` package where you can do filtering more easily. Unfortunately I don't know if you could do something similar in SQLAlchemy.

I am also not sure why you use the `EmployeeModel` as a meta model for the `Statistics` object type. If you only want to have a statistics field with `active`, `inactive` and `supscended` employees, you could also create a simple `ObjectType` without needing a base model - but maybe I just understood something wrong.